# nestjs graphql query/mutation complexity

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to implement query complexity for my nestjs v8 graphql queries, but I can't find a fully working example...

Following the docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/complexity) I created my ComplexityPlugin

```
import { GraphQLSchemaHost } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Plugin } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
  BaseContext,
  GraphQLRequestContext,
  GraphQLRequestListener,
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';
import {
  fieldExtensionsEstimator,
  getComplexity,
  simpleEstimator,
} from 'graphql-query-complexity';

@Plugin()
export class ComplexityPlugin implements ApolloServerPlugin {
  constructor(private gqlSchemaHost: GraphQLSchemaHost) {}

  requestDidStart(
    requestContext: GraphQLRequestContext<BaseContext>,
  ): void | GraphQLRequestListener<BaseContext> {
    const maxComplexity = 20;
    const { schema } = this.gqlSchemaHost;

    return {
      async didResolveOperation({ request, document }) {
        const complexity = getComplexity({
          schema,
          operationName: request.operationName,
          query: document,
          variables: request.variables,
          estimators: [
            fieldExtensionsEstimator(),
            simpleEstimator({ defaultComplexity: 1 }),
          ],
        });
        if (complexity > maxComplexity) {
          throw new GraphQLError(
            `Query is too complex: ${complexity}. Maximum allowed complexity: ${maxComplexity}`,
          );
        }
        console.log('Query Complexity:', complexity);
      },
    };
  }
}
```

then added in my module as a provider
and then in my `app.module.ts` -> imports ->

```
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      ...
      plugins: [new ComplexityPlugin()],
      ...
    }),
```

but `new ComplexityPlugin()` expects a `GraphQLSchemaHost` object as parameter... now what?

If I don't add it as a plugin into GraphQLModule.forRoot, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/johnykes/code/my-service/node_modules/@nestjs/apollo/dist/services/plugins-explorer.service.js:6:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/johnykes/code/my-service/node_modules/@nestjs/apollo/dist/drivers/apollo-federation.driver.js:9:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/johnykes/code/my-service/node_modules/@nestjs/apollo/dist/drivers/index.js:4:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/johnykes/code/my-service/node_modules/@nestjs/apollo/dist/index.js:5:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague just found the solution:

1. npm i package `"graphql-query-complexity": "...,`
2. create plugin

```
import { Plugin } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
  GraphQLRequestListener,
  GraphQLServiceContext,
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';
import { GraphQLError, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import {
  fieldExtensionsEstimator,
  getComplexity,
  simpleEstimator,
} from 'graphql-query-complexity';

@Plugin()
export class ComplexityPlugin implements ApolloServerPlugin {
  private schema: GraphQLSchema;
  constructor() {}
  async serverWillStart(service: GraphQLServiceContext) {
    this.schema = service.schema;
  }

  async requestDidStart(): Promise<GraphQLRequestListener> {
    const maxComplexity = 100;
    const schema = this.schema;

    return {
      async didResolveOperation({ request, document }) {
        const complexity = getComplexity({
          schema,
          operationName: request.operationName,
          query: document,
          variables: request.variables,
          estimators: [
            fieldExtensionsEstimator(),
            simpleEstimator({ defaultComplexity: 1 }),
          ],
        });
        if (complexity > maxComplexity) {
          throw new GraphQLError(
            `Query is too complex: ${complexity}. Maximum allowed complexity: ${maxComplexity}`,
          );
        }
      },
    };
  }
}
```

3. in `app.module.ts`, add:

```
import { ComplexityPlugin } from './modules/common/complexity.plugin';
...
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      ...
      plugins: [new ComplexityPlugin()],
      formatError: (error: GraphQLError) => {
        const graphQLFormattedError: GraphQLFormattedError = {
          ...error,
          message:
            error.extensions?.exception?.response?.message || error.message,
        };
        console.error(graphQLFormattedError);

        return {
          ...graphQLFormattedError,
          extensions: { ...graphQLFormattedError.extensions, exception: null },
        };
      },
    }),
```

4. in your graphql input args, add:

```
import { IsOptional, Max } from 'class-validator';
...
@IsOptional()
@Max(100)
@Field(() => Int, { nullable: true, description: 'Paginate first' })
public first?: number = 10;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/plugins#custom-plugins) you could just add the `ComplexityPlugin` as a provider in the `providers` array.

Comment: If I do just that, I'm getting the error I posted above (just updated the text)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a module and export this complexityplugin from there and import it in `app.module.ts` and add to providers list:

```
import { ComplexityPlugin } from './complexityPlugin';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  exports: [ComplexityPlugin],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Inside `app.module.ts`:

```
 providers: [AppService, Logger, ComplexityPlugin],
```